# How can network bandwidth(sent and recieved packets on wlan0) be displayed on the extension generic moniter?

Tags: networking, wireless, extension

i've tried various methods like **nload**. but none worked. generic monitor(genmon) is a feature that runs a command every few seconds and shows output, so i think the issue is commands that autoupdate bandwidth sent and transmit bitrate instead of giving a fixed one liner output like **whoami** or commands like it, are the thing causing it to not show a valid output.

an ideal output on genmon would look like: **out:00.0kb/s in:00.0kb/s** and would update depending on the timer set on genmon properties

*i think the only way possible for this to work is a command that doesn't give real time updating bandwidth bitrate but instead a one liner of current average bitrate at that exact moment its run*

Comment: Providing clues as to what Ubuntu product & what release of that product you're using may allow us to be more helpful in helping you.

Comment: fedora is better if no one has an answer .-.

Comment: xfce4-genmon-plugin = Generic Monitor for the Xfce4 panel in Ubuntu